# Linux sigue ejecutando versión antigua script sh

Tags: linux, shell-script

He modificado un script .sh que estaba lanzando en Linux con el comando sh. He modificado el código del script y lo he subido con winscp. Veo que actualiza el archivo pero cuando lo vuelvo a lanzar se ejecuta la versión antigua, la que había antes de las modificaciones.

Comment: Cómo se estaba lanzando? Por qué dices la versión es la última? Por qué dices que se ejecuta la versión antigua? **Edita tu pregunta** y añade toda esta información para poder ayudarte. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).